# Cypress: Add cookie to external api calls from localhost frontend

Tags: javascript, cookies, cypress

I have an **external api** deployed to a **dev server** and a **frontend** app running on **localhost**. I need to attach the cookies I get from logging in, to both my localhost and external API domain.

I can see the cookies are indeed there using `cy.getCookies({domain: null})`, however all external API calls within the react app happen without the cookies. From what I can see, you can only add cookies to the baseUrl requests, but I want to run my tests against a deployed backend (so developers don't need to have a running instance of a local backend, which is whats currently working fine as they are both on localhost)

```
cy.setCookies(name, value, {domain: localhost}) 
cy.setCookies(name, value, {domain: external_api_domain})
```

Comment: Are you expecting the dev server to see cookies set in the browser? AFIK cy.setCookies() only sets them in the browser store. Is there even a cookie store in Node? Or have I missed the point. Could you show the backend usage of cookies please.

Comment: The cookies are auth related. I want to attach them to all outgoing server requests as they are used by backend to validate user

Comment: Yes, got that from the question. What I want to know is how the server requests obtain them.

Comment: So in the network request headers, there is Headers: {
  "Connection": "...",
  "user-agent": "...",
  "accept": "*/*",
  "cookie": "..."
}.
and the server is looking at the cookies (dont know full details as i'm working on frontend only). But anyways, I did get it work in the terminal/docker now. For some reason, the cookies are being attached in terminal/docker, but when I run it though the GUI, cookies don't get added to the network call even though domain is right

Comment: Cheers, I think I got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a request originating from the app to the back-end that needs a specific cookie attached, maybe an intercept can attach them.

This is untested & on-the-fly code, may need adjusting

```js
cy.intercept('POST', my-url, (req) => 
  const cookie = cy.getCookies(name).then((cookie) => {
    req.headers['Cookie'] = `${cookie.name}=${cookie.value}`;
    req.continue()
  })
})
```

**Assumptions**

I'm assuming the frontend initiates the request that the backend then passes on to another server, and backend gets all info (including cookies) from the frontend request.

**Debugging**

You can check the backend phase is working with `cy.request()`. Ultimately you want FE to do it, but in case the problem lie in the FE and not the test `cy.request()` can be useful.

For ref [Cypress request and cookies](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-request-and-cookies/)